# How to check for default yield in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a layout, I want to output certain areas, only when there is data for them.
This is easy for named partials, but how do I check for the default yield?

```
-if content_for nil
  #content.span-24
    = yield
```

Can I actually yield nothing at all?

Comment: By "named areas" do you mean partials?

Comment: You posted some code.  Did it work for you?  What went wrong?

Comment: yes, partials and nothing happened, the content div got rendered...

Comment: are you using content_for? and missed the question mark?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, seems like I did and by making this change, I got it to work as desired :). If you want to rephrase as an answer, I can give you the points! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`content_for?(name)`

Instead of rendering the content, `content_for?` will give you the boolean you're looking for.

UPDATE

Well, for the default case, you could do something like:

```
-content = yield
-if content.present?
  #content.span-24
    =content
```

Comment: Sorry, I gave these points to early (and did not reread you rephrasing well enough): I do not need to check for a partial but the 'default' yield, the one evoked by =yield, not the one for =yield :something. But maybe this is impossible, depending on the implementation.